# I have a file called "¬" and I am confused

Tags: bash, solaris, character-encoding

I have found a file called `¬` on an old legacy Solaris server and I am confused about how to interact with it on the command line (bash 2.05).

¬ has the same function on the command line as the `home` key. When I press it, it moves the cursor to the start of the line. So if I try to remove it by typing `rm ¬` I end up with with just `rm`.

I created a file called `file` with vim and was able to insert the ¬ character. The thing is, each program sees this character differently. Some examples:

```
bash-2.05# cat file
¬

bash-2.05# vim file
¬

bash-2.05# vi file
\302\254

bash-2.05# less x
"x" may be a binary file.  See it anyway? 
<C2><AC>

bash-2.05# more file
¬

bash-2.05# ls 
¬

bash-2.05# ls -q 
??

bash-2.05# ls -b 
\302\254
```

I was able to remove the file by running `rm $(cat file)`. But my question is, how do I remove it by typing it on the command line? `rm \302\254` didn't work and I'm not sure what to do with the Hex representation that `less` gives.

Is there a special way to insert ¬ into the command line?

I realise this might be quite hard to replicate since it is so old, but I thought I would ask anyway.

Thanks,
Patrick

Comment: someone else may have a smarter answer, but if you can see (with ls -q or ls -b) that it's a single character, my fall-back in these situations is "rm -i ./?" to have rm ask you before removing any/all single-character files

Comment: If your terminal is properly setup, the character ¬ requires no special handling and `rm ¬` will work.

Comment: If you've created a file with the right character, then try `rm -i $(cat file)`

Comment: You could _try_ using the `\\ ` key before the `¬` key; eg `rm -i ./\¬` which may stop it from being interpreted as 'move to start of line'

Comment: I mean its old tech and of course I don't have this problem on other servers but the file was created somehow. On what @JeffSchaller was saying too: `bash-2.05# ls 
¬
bash-2.05# ls -q 
??
bash-2.05# ls -b 
\302\254
`

Comment: @PatrickMcMahon Please try: `rm $'\xc2\xac'`

Comment: @StephenHarris yes that's what I done, and it worked. But how can I remove it another way? Basically I can't type `¬` because it has the same function as pressing the `home` key on your keyboard. Assume I wasn't able to create the file with `¬` in it, how then could I remove it?

Comment: Does typing `Ctrl+V` and then the `¬` character types it out for you?  That may depend a lot on keyboard setup

Comment: @John1024 Genius :) That's what I am after. Thank you!

Comment: @grochmal your solution almost works too. When I press Ctrl+V then ¬ I get \302 on the command line. I am not sure how to get the remaining \254 though. Like you said, it may depend on the keyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
rm $'\xc2\xac'
```

The unicode character `¬` in UTF-8 encoding consists of bytes `c2`, `ac` and the above uses bash's `$'...'` feature to enter those bytes in hexadecimal form.

In a terminal that supports unicode, this is not necessary: one can simply use `rm ¬`.  This work-around is only needed when unicode is not supported.

#### Documentation

Bash's `$'...'` feature (added in 2.0, copied from ksh93, also available in `zsh`, `mksh` and FreeBSD `sh`) is quite powerful.  From `man bash`:

> Words of the form $'string' are treated specially.  The word expands  to  string,  with  backslash-escaped  characters
>   replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard.  Backslash escape sequences, if present, are decoded as follows:
>
> ```
>           \a     alert (bell)
>           \b     backspace
>           \e
>           \E     an escape character
>           \f     form feed
>           \n     new line
>           \r     carriage return
>           \t     horizontal tab
>           \v     vertical tab
>           \\     backslash
>           \'     single quote
>           \"     double quote
>           \nnn   the eight-bit character whose value is the octal value nnn (one to three digits)
>           \xHH   the eight-bit character whose value is the hexadecimal value HH (one or two hex digits)
>           \uHHHH the Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) character whose value is the hexadecimal value HHHH (one to four hex digits)
>           \UHHHHHHHH
>                  the  Unicode  (ISO/IEC  10646) character whose value is the hexadecimal value HHHHHHHH (one to eight hex
>                  digits)
>           \cx    a control-x character
> ```

We used only the `\xHH` form (added in 2.02) in order to enter the bytes as hexadecimal.

The `\uHHHH` one, copied from `zsh` was only added in 4.2 so wouldn't work for you, but with more recent versions of `bash` (or `zsh` or `ksh93` or `mksh` or FreeBSD `sh`), and assuming the current locale uses the UTF-8 charset, you could also do:

```
rm $'\u00AC'
```

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for adding all the compatibility and version info.

Answer (score 4):

The character `¬` is UNICODE [code point `U+00AC` or 172 (decimal)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00ac/index.htm).

When represented in `utf8` it becomes the two bytes `xC2` and `xAC` (in hex),
or the equivalent octal values of `\302` and `\254`.

That's why you can print such character in several ways in bash:

```
$ printf '\302\254'         # Add a \n to add a new line.
¬

$ printf '\xC2\xAC'
¬

$ echo -e '\0302\0254'        # Bash echo is special for requiring -e.
¬

$ echo -e '\xC2\xAC'
¬

$ echo $'\302\254'
¬

$ echo $'\xC2\xAC'
¬
```

Or even the UNICODE value directly (only if your console has been correctly set to use utf8 and since [Feb 27, 2011] Bash version 4.2, not for bash 2.05):

```
$ echo $'\u00AC'
¬

$ echo $'\U000000AC'
¬
```

Any of the methods above will work with [Command-Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)
to pass the character as an argument to the command `rm`:

```
$ rm "$(printf '\xC2\xAC')"
```

---

If your console has been set up correctly.
You may get the character `¬` printed in the screen using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> and then the home key.

[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-V)

> Unix interactive terminals use Control-V to mean "the next character should be treated literally" (the mnemonic here is "v is for verbatim")

<kbd>r</kbd><kbd>m</kbd><kbd>space</kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>home</kbd>`# what you type.`
   rm ¬`# what you get.`

---

And, of course, if [you could `copy and paste`](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-copying-with-middle-mouse-button/)

Select the character you want to use with the mouse:

```
left-click just before the character
move the mouse one character to the right
release the mouse left-click
```

Then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>insert</kbd> to copy. It may be possible that you will need to right-click (a select window will appear) and select `copy`.

And move the cursor to the place where you will like to insert the character

and press <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>insert</kbd> to paste.

With this last method you may actually write the command:

```
$ rm ¬
```

Comment: ctrl-v is a must

Answer (score 0):

By using single quotes, you may avoid all types of shell expansion and everything is taken just as it is. For example, `rm '¬'` should delete the file.

Comment: But my problem is when I press ¬, ¬ is not entered onto the command line, my cursor is instead moved to the start of the line. It acts the same way if I were to type something and then press the home key on my keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
rm -i *
```

in the directory where the file lives?